# USB to USB serial communication from PC to PC

Tags: serial-port, usb, port, communication

I am currently connecting 2 PCs using serial communication and at this time I am using a USB to Serial converter, then a serial cable, then another USB to Serial converter going into the other PC in order to get the communication sent and received.

Is there a way to program the USB ports as COM ports without these converters and still be able to transfer the serial data over the USB using software rather than hardware, thus eliminating the need for the conversions and rather have just a straight USB cable to USB cable connection?

Thanks!

Comment: A simple USB host to host connection simply won't work.  You can get plain type-A to type-A cables (I have one), but do not  try to connect two PCs together using such a cable.   I have seen host-to-host USB "cables" (there's actually back-to-back gadgets in the "cable"), and they require special drivers and userspace application.  The problem is that USB uses a master-slave protocol, and PCs typically only have host (master) ports, and almost never gadget (slave) ports.

Comment: I would suggest using a null modem Ethernet cable and communicate over TCP with sockets or hook them up to a router or network over ethernet and communicate over that in the same way (ethernet will allow the same, if not higher, communication speeds, WiFi could be slower depending on how far from the router the computers are, but would still be fairly fast.

Comment: @XanderLuciano *"I would suggest using a null modem Ethernet cable"* -- There's no such thing.  You probably mean a crossover cable.

Comment: @sawdust yea I meant crossover cable. I've been working with rs-232 a lot lately. Mixing up terms now haha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PC to PC USB communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317823/pc-to-pc-usb-communication)